# Timer not getting control textbox data

Tags: c#, timer

So im trying to execute a method from a Timer the problem is that everytime i call the method and pass a string as argument, automatically the string is set to NULL and that's weird, is there a fix or something, here is some code if you wish to look at it

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int currentHour = FixTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh tt"));
        int currentMinute = FixTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("mm tt"));
        int currentSeconds = FixTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("ss tt"));
        string currentTT = DateTime.Now.ToString("tt");

        int userHour = Settings.Default.hour;
        int userMinute = Settings.Default.minutes;
        int userSeconds = Settings.Default.seconds;
        string userTT = Settings.Default.TT;

        if (currentHour == userHour && currentMinute == userMinute &&
            currentSeconds == userSeconds && currentTT == userTT)
        {
            MakeThePost(postTextBox.Text); // the postTextBox.Text field automatically is set to null
        }
    }

    private void MakeThePost(string data)
    {
        string text = data;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
           fb.Post("me/feed", new { message = text });
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Nothing to post on facebook", "Field is   empty",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
```

**UPDATE:** So aparently the problem isnt in the timer or even in the MakeThePost the real problem is in another form iam trying to display, when its displayed the constructor makes a new Form1 object, why i make this?, because i want to have access to the controls in the main form, but when i execute the Form1 constructor to make a new object, the Form1 postTextBox control stop updating its Text property, so is there another way to access main Form controls without initializing an object?

Comment: What's going on inside `MakeThePost()` method? And what is the value of `postTextBox.Text` when it is passed into the function? (the later can be verified with a breakpoint)

Comment: Which `Timer` class are you using exactly?

Comment: @heltonbiker the value is generated by user and i always fill with text before its get to there but its automatically setting to null when it gets to the timer, and this is what MakeThePost() method does: 
    private void MakeThePost(string data)
            {
            string text = data;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
               
                    fb.Post("me/feed", new { message = text });
               
            }
          }

Comment: @Luc Morin System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Comment: Ok, so it's probably not a UI thread issue. What is the interval? Also, can you post the `MakeThePost` method (if it's not too long)? Please edit your question if you're adding code instead of adding it in comments. It makes everything clearer.

Comment: Like I said, edit your question instead.

Comment: Not too sure how to interpret your last comment. I hope you mean it in the sense that you just figured out you had the possibility to edit your question. Otherwise I'll have to think that you find my request abusive. If that's the case, let me argue that editing your question will at least "centralize" all the information and won't force other users to go through all your comments to get the whole picture. Makes sense?

Comment: Yes, i edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code doesn't seem to contain anything that would cause the `postTextBox.Text` property to become `null`.

There has to be something else in your application that nulls that property. Make sure Data Binding is not silently setting this to `null`.

Insert breakpoints both on the line calling `MakeThePost`, and on the first line of `MakeThePost`, then run the application.

See if the property is `null` only before the call, or both before and inside the method.

EDIT:

According to your latest edits, it seems you're creating a new `Form1` instance, whereas you should probably pass a reference to the existing one when instantiating `Form2`

Add a `Form2` constructor that takes a `Form1` object as parameter:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Form1 otherForm;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form2(Form1 frm) : this()
    {
        otherForm = frm;
    }

    //Other methods and properties of Form2
}
```

Then create a new instance of `Form2`:

```
Form2 secondForm = new Form2(form1Instance);
```

Now, inside the `Form2` instance, you have the `otherForm` reference, which will allow you to call public members of the `Form1` instance. You might have to change the access modifier on some `Form1` members to make them public.

Comment: I have checked with breakpoint lot of time, the problem is in the timer, i tried to use the  postTextBox.Text, in a button click event and it works excellent, the problem is on the timer there is something wrong with it, its like its not getting the controls text, data maybe the timer is running in another thread i dont know, i even tried using Console.WriteLine(postTextBox.Text) and nothing get printed, but outside it it gets printed, and it should print something because it is in real time so everytime i write something in the textbox it should print :/.

Comment: All I can offer for now is for you to post your complete VS solution (zipped) to a file sharing service, and I'll be able to take a look tomorrow. Going to make some Z's for now. Cheers.

Comment: i dont want to give all my work, i will only give it to you, and if you find a solution please post it here. :{

Comment: can i have your mail also?

Comment: That worked, now app is running Ty Luc Morin, had to pass `this` as reference when instantiating the Form2

Comment: Yes, I didn't know whether you were instantiating it from within the `Form1` instance, that's why I used the name `form1Instance` ;-) If you think my answer was helpful, please mark it as the accepted one.